# iTextSharp c# Error al crear pdf/Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, itextsharp

cuando abro mi app web localmente, descarga los documentos correctamente, pero cuando esta en el servidor ya no los descarga, no se si es necesario habilitar algún permiso, ya que estoy descargando directamente al C.
Una nota en el visual stadio para que me de permiso de descargar los documentos lo ejecuto como administrador.

```
  //Ruta del lugar donde se guardara y nombre del documento con extensión
        writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@"C:\Invoice_SN"+generatePDFViewModel.Vehicle.Id+".pdf", FileMode.Create));
```

Error:Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes copiar el mensaje de error que te da?

Comment: los permisos tambien deben ser para c: en dicha carpeta, si no tienes acceso al servidor crea una carpeta dentro de la raiz de tu aplicacion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Le tenes que asignar permisos de Modificar y Escritura a dicha carpeta para poder generar el reporte correctamente.
Te dirigis a la carpeta raíz donde se encuentra nuestro proyecto, te colocas sobre la carpeta en la cual se guardarán los archivos y presionamos segundo click, 
Propiedades > click sobre la solapa Seguridad > presionamos el botón Editar > Seleccionamos el usuario **IIS**(en caso que estes corriendo en un IIS local) o el Usuario que realice dicha acción y chequeamos el box de Modificar y el de Escritura. Presionamos Aplicar y luego Aceptar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]